# OBJ Max Polygroups number

Tags: objects, export

I have a human mesh with a lot of different polygroups representing different body parts, muscles etc...

I have around 68 polygroups. I used to export this obj into Unity and used the polygroups to select the body parts and everything worked fine. Recently when exporting the OBJ I'm losing approximately half of the polygroups in the process.

Is there a limit to the number of polygroups for one OBJ? Is it a Bug?

I'm checking "selection only", "polygroups" and "keep vertex order" in my OBJ export.